# Setting up Pocketsphinx for Python in Windows

Tags: python, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

Can somebody help me in building pocketsphinx speech recognition in windows. I'm facing difficulty in understanding the instruction provided by sphinx in ths [page](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx).

I want to develop a speech controlled computer automation application, and I'm using Python. I don't know how to install sphinx so that I can import it in the Python environment like this:

```
import pocketsphinx as ps
```

But can't make out anything from it. I was able to do it easily in Ubuntu using the

```
sudo apt-get install sphinx*
```

But, no luck with Windows. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows Solution**

Christoph Gohlke kindly added a compiled version of pocketsphinx to his unofficial extension library.

If you are running Python 3.5 (32-bit) then download: "pocketsphinx-0.0.9-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl"

Here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pocketsphinx

Then run: pip3 install "pocketsphinx-0.0.9-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl"